# How to get index of sender item from "multiplexed" event handler?

Tags: c#, event-handling, windows-8

I've got a single `OnDownloadProgress` event handler for an ordered list of `BitmapImage` items that I'm putting into a `FlipView`, and I'm wondering the best way to get the index of the sending BitmapImage in the event handler.

It's easy to do this kind of thing with objects derived from `FrameworkElement`, because they have a `Tag` property that you can set to the index (or whatever you want). But the OnDownloadProgress event is sent not by the `Image`, but by the BitmapImage, and that doesn't have a `Tag`.

I can think of a couple of ways to achieve this, but they seem hackish or heavy.

One way is by setting the Image's `Tag` to the BitmapImage instance, and then searching for that instance in the handler until you've found the sender:

```
private FlipView PhotosView;

private void AddImages(List<string> photoUrls)
{
    PhotosView.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var url in photoUrls)
    {
        var image = new Image();
        var source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
        source.DownloadProgress += OnDownloadProgress;
        image.Source = source;
        image.Tag = source;
        PhotosView.Items.Add(image);
    }
}

private void OnDownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs args)
{
    int n = 0;
    foreach (var item in PhotosView.Items)
    {
        var image = (Image)item;
        if (image.Tag == sender)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("image {0} progress={1}%", n, args.Progress);
            break;
        }
        n++;
    }
}
```

But that seems kinda wrong. A better way would be to maintain a mapping of BitmapImage instances to the index (`Dictionary<BitmapImage, int>`), and while more speed-efficient, that seems kinda heavy too.

Or, finally, I could subclass `BitmapImage` and add a `Tag` or `Index` member. Oh wait ... it's a `sealed` class. Scratch that one.

Is there a simpler or more standardized way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
private void AddImages(List<string> photoUrls)
{
    PhotosView.Items.Clear();
    int nextIndex = 0;
    foreach (var url in photoUrls)
    {
        int n = nextIndex++;
        var image = new Image();
        var source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
        source.DownloadProgress += (sender, args) => 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("image {0} progress={1}%", n, args.Progress);
        };
        image.Source = source;
        image.Tag = source;
        PhotosView.Items.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh, using a lambda is a neat idea, thanks. Why doesn't it work to use `nextIndex` directly inside the lambda -- in other words, why do you need the separate `int n` inside the loop to use in the lambda?

Comment: Wait, I think I can answer my own question by, ahem, [reading the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). It'd keep `nextIndex` around if you did that, but it'd always be incremented to the final value by the time it's used in the handler.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the reason :) It doesn't take a snapshot of the variable's value at the moment the lambda is referenced, it uses the variable itself.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. One more question (being new to modern C#). I realize early optimization is evil, but I'm curious about the performance of creating many lambda functions like this, each one bound to a different variable. Is it quite cheap, or relatively expensive, in terms of how it's implemented?

Comment: Good question. I'd imagine the compiler is smart and only creates one function with a reference to `n` similar to a parameter, but I don't know for sure. That would be a good follow-up question to ask SO.

Comment: FWIW, I just made a test application and it does indeed seem only one function `AddImages.AnonymousMethod__1` would be created.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19251/discussion-between-ben-hoyt-and-lc)

Comment: Just for the record, I decompiled the result of this "capturing lambda" with ILSpy, and what the compiler does is create a hidden class with an `int m` member variable. So each instance of the lambda in this loop is an instance of this generated class. So I'd say that's a pretty efficient approach.